# jQuery Dialog Fly-in

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am trying to have a dialog fly-in from a side of my screen, let's say, the top. I was able to do it with some dirty hacks, but, its performance is pretty unimpressive. Here is my code:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
  $('<div class="myDialog" title="Test"></div>').dialog({
    'position' : 'top'
  }).dialog('widget').css({
    'position' : 'fixed',
    'top' : '0',
    'height' : '0'
  }).animate({
    'height' : '200'
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'top' : '40%'
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

There weren't any effects in the jQuery UI which handled this the way I was hoping. Is there a way I can improve its performance so it is nice a smooth? I'd like to avoid using a plugin, if possible.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** Ok, here is what I accidentally came up with, with the help of smellofgreen:

```
$(':button').click(function() {
  $('<div class="myDialog" title="Test"></div>').dialog({
    'position' : 'top'
  }).dialog('widget').css({
    'position' : 'fixed',
    'top' : $(document).height()+200, //Here was the crown-jewel
    'display' : 'none'
  }).slideDown('slow', function() { //Thanks to smellofgreen
    $(this).animate({
      'top' : '40%'
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar with only using the easing plugin using the slideUp() / slideDown() methods:

```
$('body').append('<div id="terminal-status"></div>');
$('#terminal-status').slideUp(0).load( /* load your content */ ), function () {
    $('#terminal-status').slideDown(900,'easeOutCirc');
}
```

Not shown is the CSS that positions it as you wish.

Comment: so close. Performance is much better, but there is still a slight pause between the sliding down, and moving down. So, it doesn't look natural. Is there a way I can close this gap?

Comment: whoa! I just made a change that totally worked! I used your idea for the "slide" technique. I just needed mine to slide down. I'll post my code above. +1 for you!